# Clipping a video in C++ OpenCV from a specified start and end point

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I want to clip a video in C++ OpenCV from a specified start and end point. I understand that we can use the following VideoCapture properties for this purpose.

```
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC or `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`
```

But how do I exactly clip a video using any one of the above properties and write it on another video file? I don't find any method to read the video file from a specified relative position in millisecond or from a relative frame index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on some simple tools like this recently. It builds and runs for me with no issue. Here you go:

```
// Code borrowed heavily from the OpenCV samples

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{    
    // Command line argument parsing
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv,
        "{help h usage ?|               | print this message        }"
        "{@vid_name     |               | video file                }"
        "{@frame_num    | 0             | start frame               }"
        "{@frame_count  | 100           | frames to extract         }"
        );

    if (parser.has("help"))
    {
        parser.printMessage();
        return 0;
    }

    string inputFilename = parser.get<string>("@vid_name");
    int frameNumber = parser.get<int>("@frame_num");
    int frameCount = parser.get<int>("@frame_count");
    if (!parser.check())
    {
        parser.printMessage();
        parser.printErrors();
        return -1;
    }

    // Open video
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(inputFilename);
    if ( !capture.isOpened() )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open video\n");
        return -1;
    }
    double fps = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    size_t width = (size_t)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    size_t height = (size_t)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    Size imgSz(width,height);
    size_t totalFrames = (size_t)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    // Open output video files        
    VideoWriter vidwriter;
    int codec = CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    vidwriter.open("clip.avi", codec, fps, imgSz, true);
    if ( !vidwriter.isOpened() ) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open an output video file for write\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Extract subset of frames
    Mat frame;
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameNumber);
    for (int frameInd = frameNumber; frameInd < frameNumber+frameCount; ++frameInd)
    {
        capture >> frame;
        if ( frame.empty() ) 
            break;
        vidwriter.write(frame);
    }
    capture.release();

    printf("Success.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect any quality loss with this code? In other words, will the video be re-encoded? In case it does, do you think there's a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a `VideoCapture`of your video file, you can use the property `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` and calculate easily the frame number of the starting and ending time of the clip you want to cut.

Just create a `VideoWriter` use the `set` property `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` to the frame number of the initial time and start adding frames to the `VideoWriter` until you reach the second frame number you calculated before.

Answer (score 0):

#### Note

Use `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` might be more humanize.

I write the following Python code to clip video from source.

#### Python Code

```
import cv2 as cv
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Video clip")
    parser.add_argument('--input', required=True, type=str, help="Input video")
    parser.add_argument('--output', required=True, type=str, help="Output Video")
    parser.add_argument('--start', required=True, type=float, help="Start time in seconds")
    parser.add_argument('--duration', required=True, type=float, help="Duration time in seconds")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def video_clip(args):
    vid = cv.VideoCapture(args.input)
    target_fps = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    target_width = round(vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    target_height = round(vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    frame_count = round(vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    # # Notice: This is not actually length of video, this might be longer
    # # Check v1.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0 or 1) for more information
    video_length = frame_count / target_fps

    out = cv.VideoWriter(args.output, cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), target_fps, (target_width, target_height))

    time_start = max(0, args.start)
    time_stop = min(args.duration + time_start, video_length) * 1000

    vid.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, time_start * 1000)
    while vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) < time_stop :
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        out.write(frame)
    vid.release()
    out.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    video_clip(args)
```

#### Usage

To clip a video, just use the following command:

```
python video_clip.py --input input.mp4 --output output.mp4 --start 10 --duration 10
```

- `--input`: Input video
- `--output`: Output Video
- `--start`: Start time in seconds
- `--duration`: Duration time in seconds

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions. Please note - the OP posted a C++ OpenCV question.

Comment: My answer was different from the OP, we use different video property. What's more,  Python code is easier to use actually. Just offer another option for the asker.